# Win32API ReadFile Call worked and now never returns after call

Tags: winapi

When the code executes the ReadFile the call never returns. Previously the way I saved the Handle and passed it from function to function was not properly done. I changed the way the handle was stored and it works with all of the other calls in the program except the read. I have looked and compared all of the variables used and they check out.

Here is the code. instance->Master has the handle from the create. I added a GetCommState call before the read and it executes correctly.
'''

```
ATCA_STATUS swi_silab_receive_byte(ATCASWIMaster_t* instance, uint8_t* data)
{
    uint8_t retries = 3;
    DWORD NoBytesRead = 0;        // Bytes read by ReadFile()
    uint8_t SerialBuffer;   //Buffer to send and receive data
    DWORD Byte_count = (DWORD)sizeof(SerialBuffer);

    ATCA_STATUS status;

    while ((retries > 0) && (NoBytesRead < 1))
    {
        //Read data and store in a buffer
        status = GetCommState(instance->hMaster, &instance->dcbMaster);
        if (status == 0)
            printf(" init GetcommState failed\n");
        status = ReadFile(instance->hMaster, &SerialBuffer, Byte_count, &NoBytesRead, NULL);
        retries--;
    }
    if (status == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError! in ReadFile()\n\n");
        return ATCA_TIMEOUT;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Read Success Serial Buffer = %x\n", &SerialBuffer);
        *data = SerialBuffer;
        //printf("Read Success Data = %x\n", *data);

        return ATCA_SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

'''

Comment: Check the SetCommTimeouts, otherwise ReadFile may well block.

Comment: According to [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile),you can refer to its Remarks.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy to state there is no issue in the code. Thanks to Zhu Song who made a comment about reading the ReadFile remarks. If there is no data to read then readfile will just wait. A check with the logic analyzer showed the write executes but doesn't actually write, hence the read is not actually able to read.

Thanks to everyone who commented

Answer (score 0):

According to [ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile):

The ReadFile function returns when one of the following conditions occur:

- The number of bytes requested is read.
- A write operation completes on the write end of the pipe.
- An asynchronous handle is being used and the read is occurring asynchronously.
- An error occurs.

To cancel all pending asynchronous I/O operations, use either:

- [CancelIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelio)—this function only cancels operations issued by the calling thread for the specified file handle.
- [CancelIoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func)—this function cancels all operations issued by the threads for the specified file handle.